# Binary Search Implementation Using Slicing

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity, binary-search

Regarding the binary search implementation given below:

```
def bin_search(arr, key):
    n = len(arr)
    if n < 2:
       return (0 if (n == 1 and arr[0] == key) else None)
    m = int(0.5 * n)
    if arr[m] > key:
       return bin_search(arr[:m], key)
    result = bin_search(arr[m:], key)
    return (result + m if result != None else None)
```

For the above binary search implementation, time complexity will be affected as we are taking slice of an array and space complexity too as list slicing in python creates a new list object. For improving the above implementation, I am thinking of introducing lower and upper bound variables just as in its original implementation. But it will modify the above code implementation completely.

Can you please let me know how to modify the above implementation so that the time and space complexity of it is improved and is my understanding regarding its complexity correct?

Comment: You should just pass the original array to the recursed function, and high/low boundaries of your search.  Avoids generating all those slices.

Comment: @RufusVS I tried doing the same. But it will modify the existing implementation completely and give an all together new implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is iterative solution with time complexity of `O(log(n))` and space complexity of `O(1)`. Instead of modifying array you just modify the positions of pointers. I mean `left/right` by pointers.

```
def binary_search(array, target):
    return binary_search_helper(array, target, 0, len(array) - 1)


def binary_search_helper(array, target, left, right):
    while left <= right:
        middle = (left + right) // 2
        match = array[middle]

        if target == match:
            return middle
        elif target < match:
            right = middle - 1
        else:
            left = middle + 1

    return -1
```

**Recursive solution:** I don't see a way to improve complexity with a *slight* changes since you need to work with positions instead of array itself. That will affect your base case and function calls. Here is my attempt to reduce space complexity from `O(n)` to `O(log(n))`.

```
def bin_search(arr, key, left=0, right=len(arr) - 1):
    # Should change base case since we modify only pointers
    if left > right:
        return None

    # since we are not modifying our array working with length will not work
    m = int(0.5 * (left + right))

    if arr[m] == key:
        return m
    elif arr[m] > key:
       return bin_search(arr, key, left, m - 1)
    else:
        return bin_search(arr, key, m + 1, right)
```

PS: Need to create `arr` beforehand or create another caller function since we define `right=len(arr) - 1` in function definition. I would recommend using caller function like this:

```
def binary_search_caller(arr, key):
    return bin_search(arr, key, 0, len(array) - 1)
```

And change function definition to:

```
def bin_search(arr, key, left, right):
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks but for the implementation mentioned in the question how can we modify it slightly so that complexity is improved?

Comment: So you want recursive solution with a better complexity?

Comment: Yes because the implementation has to be modified slightly.

Comment: Thank you. It helps

Comment: had a query. For the implementation given in the question would the time complexity be O(klogn) where k is the size of the slice or it will remain unchanged?

Comment: @tendo Only thing is getting affected is space complexity since you are creating extra space in each recursive function call. Time complexity would remain unchanged.

Comment: got it thanks sorry my bad for time complexity for len of list i was taking it as O(k) instead of O(1) and with your implementation it will reduce the space complexity from O(n) to O(1)?

Comment: when implementing recursive solution, space complexity can be O(log(n)) depending on how memory is used in recursive call stacks and it depends on the language of choice. That is why it is recommended to use iterative solution over recursive one.  But usually we say it is O(1) since we are not storing anything in variables or something.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation